# Backbone view event atacched to all views

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I'm doing my first application in backbone and i get a strange thing happening trying to attach an event.

I got this code so far:

```
//View for @girl, EDIT action
GirlEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(el, attr) {
        this.variables = attr;
        console.log(attr);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template( $("#girl_edit").html(), this.variables );
        $(this.el).html( template );
        $("#edit_girl").modal('show');
    }
});

//View for @girl
GirlView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(el, attr) {
        this.variables = attr;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template( $("#girl_template").html(), this.variables );
        $(this.el).html( $(this.el).html() + template );
    },
    events: {
        "click p.modify": "modify"
    },
    modify: function() {
        //calls to modify view
        new GirlEditView({el : $("#edit_girl")}, this.variables);
    }
});


//One girl from the list
Girl = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.view = new GirlView({el : $("#content")}, this.attributes );
    }
});

//all the girls
Girls = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Girl,
});




//do magic!
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Underscore template modification
    _.templateSettings = {
        escape : /\{\[([\s\S]+?)\]\}/g,
        evaluate : /\{\[([\s\S]+?)\]\}/g,
        interpolate : /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
    }

    //get initial data and fill the index
    var list = [];
    $.getJSON('girls.json', function(data) {
        list = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            list.push( new Girl(val) );
        });

        var myGirls = new Girls(list);
        console.log( myGirls.models);
    });
});
```

As you can see.

I'm using a collection to store all the girls and the data comes from a REST api in ruby.

Each girls create a new model instance and inside i attached a view instance.

I don't know if it's a good practice but i can't think a better way to do it.

Each view makes a  content with a unique id. girl-1 girl-2 and go on.

Now, the template have a edit button.
My original idea is to attack the onclick event and trigger the edit view to get rendered.

That is working as expected.

The proble so far is:

When the events triggers, all the collection (girls) fire the edit view, not the one that "owns" the rendered view.

My question is what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the edit-views come up because all the GirlViews are using the same `el`:

```
this.view = new GirlView({el : $("#content")}, this.attributes );
```

and then you render be appending more HTML:

```
render: function() {
    var template = _.template( $("#girl_template").html(), this.variables );
    $(this.el).html( $(this.el).html() + template );
}
```

Backbone events are bound using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the view's `el`. So, if multiple views share the same `el`, you'll have multiple `delegate`s attached to the same DOM element and your events will be a mess of infighting.

You have things a little backwards: models do not own views, views watch models and collections and respond to their events. You'll see this [right in the documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> [...] There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, [...]

Generally, you create a collection, `c`, and then create the view by handing it that collection:

```
var v = new View({ collection: c })
```

or you create a model, `m`, and then create a view wrapped around that model:

```
var v = new View({ model: m })
```

Then the view binds to events on the collection or model so that it can update its display as the underlying data changes. The view also acts as a controller in Backbone and forwards user actions to the model or collection.

Your initialization should look more like this:

```
$.getJSON('girls.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        list.push(new Girl(val));
    });

    var myGirls = new Girls(list);
    var v       = new GirlsView({ collection: myGirls });
});
```

and then `GirlsView` would spin through the collection and create separate `GirlView`s for each model:

```
var _this = this;
this.collection.each(function(girl) {
    var v = new GirlView({ model: girl });
    _this.$el.append(v.render().el);
});
```

Then, `GirlView` would render like this:

```
// This could go in initialize() if you're not certain that the
// DOM will be ready when the view is created.
template: _.template($('#girl_template').html()),
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    return this;
}
```

The result is that each per-model view will have its own distinct `el` to localize the events. This also makes adding and removing a GirlView quite easy as everything is nicely wrapped up in its own `el`.

Comment: Ok i think i get the concept of models-views in backbone, i made the changes but now nothing shows up in the page http://pastebin.com/96vhsDPu

Comment: @nax: You're not rendering your `GirlsView` anywhere; and the `this.collection.each` loop would probably be better in `render` rather than `initialize`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3fHkh/